# Untouched CF Prod Code stopped working, related to redirects/Inserts/Updates

Tags: coldfusion

My production code worked fine for the last month and last week.
However, after our company main page was overhauled (BCM.EDU), my production CF forms stopped working, specifically for the following tags:

**CFLOCATION, CFINSERT, CFUPDATE**, Add/Change records using **CFQUERY**

When I click the buttons to perform the actions above, the page just stays the same and no updates/additions are done to the SQL database. Other stuff may have failed as well and not yet discovered. The code for these pages has NOT changed recently or over the past month.
I did not post any code because I did not think it was necessary. It's just generic textbook, basic CF.

It just stopped working overnight!

When the code was working I was told production uses CF9 and development uses CF7MX.
Now, only the DEV code works.

I have requested assistance and an explanation from the support group but they have yet to respond.

Has anyone encountered this situation?
Is this because of configuration changes, security or a new version of CF?

Comment: Talk to your hosting providers.

Comment: Check your logs to see if exceptions are being thrown.

Comment: Verify the Datasource connection if that doesn't reveal something. See if you can get the server put into debug mode for your IP. If they won't do that, put up a very simple page that queries the DB. Wrap it in a try catch, and dump any cfcatch details

Comment: *put up a very simple page that queries the DB ...dump any cfcatch details* That is a nice simple test you can try yourself while waiting for more information from your host/provider.